# Запуск двух классов Java одновременно

Tags: java

Есть два файла с классами под названием "classA.class" и "classB.class" в папке "C:\Folder\". Моя программа имеет лишь строчки `String classA = "classA"; String classB = "classB";`. Как запустить оба класса одновременно? То есть запустить команду `public static void run() {...}`, присутствующую в этих классах.

Comment: Что в данном случае значит запустить? Какая связь между class-ами и exe-файлом?

Comment: Добавил правку в вопрос. Прочитайте ещё раз.

Comment: Стало немного яснее, но не совсем. Предположу, что Вам нужен батник, который запустит две копии exe для каждого из класса. Стандартная команда Windows start поможет запустить их одновременно. Точнее вторая копия не будет дожидаться завершения первой

Comment: Добавил ещё правку. Прочитайте ещё раз).

Comment: @Lesperanza, я тоже ничего не понял. У вас есть два класса (не String,  а что-то такое, что вы сами написали). Внутри них есть метод и вы хотите его выполнить, когда создаёте объект класса. Так?

Comment: @LEQADA, Да. Просто название класса лежит в строчке (String). И мне надо, чтобы метод "run()" каждого из классов, допустим, при нажатии на кнопку в окошке, запускался. Мне нужен лишь код, который будет выглядеть примерно так: [String classA...; Class.getByName(classA); ...startMethod("run");...//и тоже самое для второго класса]. Если честно, не знаю, как правильно написать примерный код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, надо определиться, находится папка c:\Folder\ в classpath или нет. Если да, то первый шаг пропускается, иначе - надо создать новый загрузчик классов, указав ему эту папку. Про загрузчики классов читайте отдельно, это слишком крупная тема для формата "вопрос-ответ" (поэтому лучше если классы будут в classpath).

---

Далее, надо определиться со способом запуска. Если вы заранее знаете имена классов - то вам надо лишь создать два потока:

```
new Thread(() -> classA.run()).start();
new Thread(() -> classB.run()).start();
```

Еще красивее будет, если метод `run` - не статический, а классы `classA` и `classB` реализуют интерфейс `Runnable`:

```
new Thread(new classA()).start();
new Thread(new classB()).start();
```

Если же имена классов для запуска вам заранее не известны - то надо воспользоваться рефлексией:

```
static void RunClassByName(String name) {
  try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(name);
    Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
    Runnable runnable = Runnable.class.cast(instance); // Я использую именно такую форму, чтобы сделать возможное исключение проверяемым
    runnable.run();
  } catch (...) {
    // Тут надо как-то обработать это исключение
  }
}

...

new Thread(() -> RunClassByName("classA")).start();
new Thread(() -> RunClassByName("classB")).start();
```

Возможные исключения, которые надо бы обработать, смотри в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) к используемым методам.

В этом варианте сам поиск нового класса, создание экземпляра и запуск происходят в отдельном потоке. Также предполагается, что классы `classA` и `classB` реализуют `Runnable`, в противном случае вместо вызова `newInstance` вам потребуется найти статический метод `run` и вызвать его:

```
static void RunClassByName(String name) {
  try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(name);
    Method runMethod = clazz.getMethod("run");
    runMethod.Invoke(null);
  } catch (...) {
    // Тут надо как-то обработать это исключение
  }
}
```

---

Но все, что было написано выше, касается лишь однократного вызова методов (при старте программы, к примеру). Для постоянных вызовов одного и того же метода рефлексия - слишком медленная. Если все, что вам надо - это указать обработчик события, то лучше использовать лямбды:

```
Runnable methodA = () -> classA.runA();
Runnable methodB = () -> classB.runB();
Runnable methodC = () -> classB.runC();

...

methodA.run();
```

Вам же все равно надо где-то указывать названия классов? Ну так можно вместо этого указывать сразу имена заранее заготовленных переменных или полей.

Если же вам обязательно нужны строки - тоже не беда:

```
Map<String, Runnable> map = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
map.put("methodA", () -> classA.runA());
map.put("methodB", () -> classA.runB());
map.put("methodC", new classC()); // специально показываю разные возможные варианты

...

map.get("methodA").run();
```

Comment: У него же вроде требуется static run запустить. Зачем new instance?

Comment: @banme я показываю все возможные варианты. Как я понял, автор ищет варианты по организации своего кода, и его текущее решение может не быть окончательным.

Comment: вот это `runnable()` точно правильно? Не `runnable.run()`? Если что, в новомодных лямбдах ещё даже не пытался разбираться.

Comment: @banme привычка с C#. Разумеется, надо метод `.run()` вызывать.

Comment: Не работает, выводит ошибку "java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast classA to java.lang.Runnable
"

Comment: @Lesperanza Если у Вас static run, то использовать второй вариант RunClassByName

Comment: У меня "public void run()". Не работает всё-равно.

Comment: Чтобы работал вариант Runnable, убедитесь, что классы объявлены, как реализация интерфейса Runnable: `class ClassA implements Runnable { ... }`